# Add language to default .net environment settings

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

The VS is set to default VisualBasic, but I need to import existing C# projects into my solution, where I already have the VB project.

But when I try to add an existing project to the solution and navigate to the C# project - I can't see the project file. From the drop-down settings menu I have the possibility to import only `.vbproj` and other `.vb...`

I tried to create new C# project, but I can only make VB and some office tools and Web. I don't have C# possibility, so I suppose it's because the Visual Studio has been set to VB only.

How can I add/change settings so I can create/import C# projects, as well?

**EDIT:** I tried going to Tools->Import and Export Settings... but I didn't have the possibility to import C# development settings or whatsoever. I could only add Project dev. set. and VB dev. set.

P.S. It's not my computer, so I was not the one to install the Visual Studio and I don't know what settings were set/installed.

Comment: Have you installed "C#" via Visual Studio installer?

Comment: @AlirezaMaddah - I don't know. It's not my computer, so I was not the one to install the Visual Studio and I don't know what settings were set/installed. I will write that as an edit to the question

Comment: @Syspect - If you are unable to create a C# project then the version of Visual Studio does not support creating a C# project and thus you will be unable to create a C# project.  The owner of the pc needs to either install Visual Studio C# Express or the full professional paid version of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the Visual Studio Express Edition for VB.NET; then that's not possible.

Answer (score 2):

Visual Basic will most likely be selected as your default programming language. When creating a new project you can select a different language by collapsing the 'Other Languages' folder. If this does not contain C# you will have to install C# support for VS.

You can do this at 'Add and Remove Programs' or 'Programs and Features' and then changing the Visual Studio installation. Select the C# feature and after the installation completes you should now be able to open, add and create projects with C#.